# C Plus Plus not calculating correctly

Tags: c++

I made a program that calculates the area of a circle. You have the option to enter a diameter or a radius. After you select one of them, you enter the value. Then it tells you what you entered and gives you the answer. But the answer isn't correct. For example, I enter 'r' then type '3' it gives me:

```
This is a calculator that calculates the area of a circle.
To get started, type 'd' (no quotes or caps) to enter a diamater.
Type 'r' (no quotes or caps) to enter a radius.
r
You chose radius, now please enter a number.
3
3 * 2 * 3.14 = 40828.1
```

It doesn't look right, as you can see. Perhaps C++'s Pi variable is outdated?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> // Importing math.h so I can use the M_PI variable.
using namespace std;

int main() {
char choice;
float result = 0.0; // Set to zero to init and stop the IDE from complaining.
float number = 0.0;

cout << "This is a calculator that calculates the area of a circle." << endl;
cout << "To get started, type 'd' (no quotes or caps) to enter a diamater." << endl;
cout << "Type 'r' (no quotes or caps) to enter a radius." << endl;

cin >> choice;

choice = tolower(choice); // Making it lower case so it's easier for compiler to recoginize.


switch (choice) {
case 'r':
        cout << "You chose radius, now please enter a number." << endl;
        cin >> number;
        result = choice*choice*M_PI;
break;

case 'd':
        cout << "You chose radius, now please enter a number." << endl;
        cin >> number;
        result = choice*M_PI;
break;

default:
        cout << "You entered an invalid character. Please only enter 'r' or 'd' (no quotes or caps)" << endl;
break;
}

if (choice == 'r')
{
    cout << number << " * 2 * 3.14 = " << result << endl;
} 
else if (choice == 'd') {
    cout << number << " * 3.14 = " <<  result << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Nothing here cause you didn't do simple stuff correctly..." << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: why you have both a **switch case** and **if statement**

Comment: @Lamar, I'm practicing C++, since I'm new, so I'm just practicing different stuff.

Comment: `result = choice*choice*M_PI;` but `choice` is `r`, which is 114 in ASCII. So, the result you get makes perfect sense. You probably meant `result = number*number*M_PI;`

Comment: *Perhaps C++'s Pi variable is outdated?* I didn't know that Pi goes out of date??

Comment: @NeilKirk I mean they probably gave the C++ Pi variable a different value back then

Comment: @NolanD. Why? Pi doesn't change.

Comment: @NeilKirk I mean like back in 80s or 90s if the Scientist had a different calculation for Pi

Comment: @NolanD. i hope my explanation helps

Comment: Yeah, back in the days when they thought Pi was exactly equal to 22/7 or 3.

Comment: And now we have versions for PI :-)

Comment: the area when having diameter is `PI*pow(diameter, 2)/4`, not `result = choice*M_PI;` like you wrote, which is probably perimeter formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new couple things you need to remember:

**switch case and if/else statement** are pretty similar, therefore you don't need to use them both at the same time on same task.

When the program runs the user inputs a value either **r** or **d** , that value get passed to the **choice** variable. The switch case compares its own cases to the choice value and if both value are equal, it will run that case code block and if they are not it will run the **default code**.

Now inside the case, you are asking for the radius, once you get the radius,

```
 result = number * number * M_PI;
```

OR

```
result = pow(number,2.0) * M_PI;
```

And also there is a big difference between **cout<<"2*3"; and cout<<2*3;**

> The first example will display 2*3 into your screen.
>
> The second example will display the result of 2*3 into the screen
>   **6**, the reason you it calculates because there is not quotation mark around it

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Shoulr calculation of `result` use `choise`???

Looks like you have a typo. Replace `choise` woth `number` in the

```
result = choice*choice*M_PI;
```

And in the

```
result = choice*M_PI;
```

Using `choise` in calculation actually uses its ASCII code. This explains the big values that you get in the `result`.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = choice*choice*M_PI;
```

this should be

```
result = number * number * M_PI;
```

also you are printing

```
* 2 * 3.14 =
```

should be

```
^ 2 * 3.14 =
```